# Error `bunx: command not found` after installing bun

Tags: typescript, ubuntu, bun

Tried to install next.js with bunx in ubuntu after bun for testing. but I'm getting this error

`bunx: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

The bun team [still working](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/4598) on it but you can define **bun x** as **bunx** with this code in your ubuntu terminal

```
echo -e '\nalias bunx="bun x"' >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```